# How to parse a string number into a BigDecimal

Tags: java, regex, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safe String to BigDecimal conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752578/safe-string-to-bigdecimal-conversion)

Is there any ultimate parse function in java which can analyze type of the number given in string and return its value in object of class Number or similar.
I would like to convert string into bigDecimal or Number and put t into collection, sometimes I have string like `2.23` or `2,23` or `2` or BigInteger like `233242424242424242`.

Comment: Maybe but explanation under is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all you want is to parse a `String` to a `BigDecimal`, you can use the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) that gets a string as a argument. The constructor takes care of the basic parsing.

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(str);
```

For complex parsing (involving thousands separators), you can use the methods in the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class with [`setParseBigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setParseBigDecimal%28boolean%29) set to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

The documentation of the Double method has an excellent example of the regexp you are looking for:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: The question was about BigDecimal, The answer concerns Double.