# String[] to BigDecimal[]

Tags: java, android

I have citation issuing android app that an end user can enter values then 'store' them as defaults, so the next time they go to issue a citation, the default values are prepopulated...

i am able to store a `BigDecimal[]` to `String[]` but I'm having the hardest time getting the `String[]` back into `BigDecimal[]`

can anyone help me please?

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
edit.putString(SOMETHING[i], String.valueOf(aSomething.getOtherThing(i)));
}
```

this works to store it as string
but I cant get it back to BigDecimal, i've tried this, among other things:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
aSomething.setOtherThing(BigDecimal.valueOf(SOMETHING[i]));
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could just simply use

```
new BigDecimal(str);
```

In your case it would be

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    aSomething.setOtherThing(new BigDecimal(SOMETHING[i]));
}
```

But you should know that this is not safe and it may throw a NumberFormatException if the value is not a valid representation of a BigDecimal.

Consider checking this [Safe String to BigDecimal conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752578/safe-string-to-bigdecimal-conversion)

Comment: Im getting "setOtherThing BigDecimal[] cannot be applied to BigDecimal"

Comment: @buradd You will have to make the array by yourself. Like using a map function for example.