# Java input Prompt for BigDecimal

Tags: java, input, prompt, bigdecimal

I need users to be able to input numbers in the BigDecimal data type.

`Numbers[i] = (BigDecimal)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Type in a Number",0);`

This is the code I tried to use but I get an error saying "Cannot cast from String to BigDecimal."

Any Advice?

Comment: Please google before posting. Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3752616/3409880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read docs first. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

BigDecimal has a constructor which takes a string as a representation of your decimal.

```
Number num = new BigDecimal(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Type in a Number",0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the constructor:

```
Numbers[i] = new BigDecimal(
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Type in a Number",0));
```