# Problems with parsing String to double

Tags: java

I have a string having number as 12345686844.71 and I need to convert this into double so that I can get the same value as in string to use this in double value in formula..
This was tried by me , but this is not working and we are getting the value as 1.2345686844 .... actually it should be the value same as stored in string

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(string)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between Double.parseDouble(string) and Double.valueOf(string)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577610/what-is-difference-between-double-parsedoublestring-and-double-valueofstring)

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. You're printing the number in science notation.

Instead of `System.out.print()` use the following:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(string)
System.out.printf("dexp: %f\n", d);
```

If you have pasted the whole value of your double you would see that there is `E` almost at the end of the printed value. It stands for `multiplied by 10 to the power of` and there is the exponent.

What's important isn't what is being printed but rather what's in the memory. The value stored in `d` is correct. The printed value might have many useless trailing zeroes.

You can also use the `DecimalFormat` class:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use BigDecimal class provided in java.

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(str);
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752626/7135460

Comment: ok this is fine but I am trying to store the same value in double based formula for example : double z = x*(y/a) where x is double and y is double and a is big decimal

Answer (score -3):

double d = Double.parseDouble(string)

Comment: This was tried by me , but this is not working and we are getting the value as 1.2345686844 .... actually it should be the value same as stored in string

Comment: Why did you copy/pasted a part of the question??